# MongoDB doesn't show fields which are empty or NaN

Tags: mongodb

I have a csv which has some columns with no value like 'nan' or 'NaN'. And I am storing that in MongoDB, but the columns don't show up or is seen in the DB, after the upload is done.

If there are five columns A,B,C,D and E along with an timestamp index 'Time', then I can see only A,B,C,D in the database, if E doesnt have any value in it.

Have anyone faced this issue before and know of any way to retrieve all columns?

Comment: How are you uploading the CSV?

Comment: Using an API written in Python

Comment: THis is your CSV uploader. Not MongoDB. Its ignoring missing values.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. Let me check that.